# Forming a multiplicative group $\mod n$ whose order is a prime number

Tags: group-theory

I've recently started abstract algebra and now studying integers $\mod n$ under *multiplication*. I'm particularly interested in finding a group whose order is a prime number. But it seems there are no such groups as $\phi(n)$ doesn't seem to be a prime for any $n \gt 3$. I'd like to have a confirmation that there are no groups $\mod n$ whose order is a prime number ? Appreciate your time. Thanks :)

Comment: There are two different questions here.  Is there a group of order n where n is a prime number? And Is there an n such that that the group of integers under multiplication mod n has order that is a prime number.

Comment: Ah right, I'll edit the title and try make it less ambiguous. Ty @BrianBorchers

Comment: $\phi(n)$ is even for $n>2$. But $\phi(3)=\phi(6)=2$, which is prime.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a nice closed form for the values of the $\phi$-function:

> $\phi(n) = \Pi_{p | n} (p^k-p^{k-1})$, where $k$ is the highest power of $p$ that divides $n$.

If $p$ is prime this evaluates to $p-1$, which for $p > 2$ is even and hence not prime. For $p^k$, $k>1$, the number $p^k - p^{k-1} = p^{k-1}(p-1)$, which also must be composite. And if $n$ is composite, then $\phi(n)$ will be the product of these composite factors.

In short, your guess is right: there is no $n$ whose multiplicative group has prime order.

Comment: Oh if I understand correctly $\phi(p^k)=p^k-p^{k-1}$ is never a prime; consequently there cannot exist multiplicative groups mod n of prime order. I feel I get this. Thank you so much!

Comment: $\phi (p^k)=p^k-p^{k-1}$.

Comment: Thanks, fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need two results as follows:

> $\Bbb{Z}_n-\{0\}$ is a group under multiplication iff $n$ is prime.
>
> Let $n$ be a natural number. Then the set of all natural numbers which are relatively prime to $n$ forms a group under multiplication $\bmod n$, which is of order $\phi(n)$.

Comment: I think $\mathbb{Z_n} = \{0,1,2,\cdots, n-1\}$. If so, I'm pretty sure you meant $\mathbb{Z_n}\setminus \{0\}$ in the first result. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

It can't be any complete residue system $\mod n$ as zero has no multiplicative inverse.

It can't be any $\mathbb Z_n\setminus\{0\}$ (everything but $0$) for any $3 > 3$ because if $n-1$ is prime then $n$ is not (except for $n=3$) and such a residue system would have zero divisors.

[If $n =3$ we have $\{1,2\}$ is a group with order $2$ which is fairly simple.]

We do know that if $p>3$ is a prime then $\mathbb Z_p\setminus\{0\} $ **is** a group under multiplication $\mod n$ but it has order $p-1$ which is not prime (unless $p = 3$).

Now if you are allowed "incomplete" modulo systems then $\{2^n \mod 31\} = \{1,2,4,8,16\}$ is a group with an order of $5$ and any $\{a^n\mod a^p-1\}$ will be a group under multiplication mod $a^p$ with order $p$ for any prime $p$ and $a > 1$.  But I doubt that's what you had in mind.